# Unable to include .txt files when converting a .py to .exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have recently made an app that does automatic assigment submissions using selenium. I would like to convert this .py file to a .exe so i can give it to others to use on thier computers.

This is the current directory of the project:

```
C:
   canvas automation
       chromedriver.exe
       main.py
       canvas_subjects.txt
```

In the main.py file, it uses canvas_subjects.txt file as below:

```
with open('c:/canvas automation/canvas_subjects.txt', 'r+') as subjects:
    chrome_dir = 'C:/PythonProjects/Web Scraping/Selenium/chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_dir)
    driver.minimize_window()
    if subjects.read() != '':
       # does the rest of the program here
```

When i try and convert main.py to .exe, running the .exe file produces the error:

```
Failed to execute main script
```

I'm guessing that when it runs the python script, it cannont find the following directory:

```
c:/canvas automation/canvas_subjects.txt
```

To convert this file to .exe, i have tried using pyinstaller:

```
C:\Users\user> pip install pyinstaller
C:\Canvas Automation> pyinstaller main.py
# also tried
C:\Canvas Automation> pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py
```

.exe file is created but outputs the same error.

I have tried auto-py-to-exe but it says that you need to incorporate the following code into your script so that the .exe file can find the directory but i do not understand how to use it:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include a txt file in an exe like that. You have 2 solutions here:

1. Deliver your .txt file alongside the .exe like a part of the installation
2. Put the content of your text file inside a .py file as a string variable.

> NB1: Are you sure you need an exe? could you not distribute it as a python soft, needing python to be executed?
> NB2: Either way, you really should not use absolute paths like 'c:...' if you plan to distribute your soft

Comment: thanks for your help. If i plan to distribute, can you suggest how i should setup the file

Comment: However, it does make sense to just not make a .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble including .txt files, try the following command to enable it in order:
CTRL+A
Backspace
CTRL+S
ALT+F4

If problems persist, please let me know.